# Wordpress: Extend main div into full width of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

With the help of @rnevius ([Remove sidebar from wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728266/remove-sidebar-from-wordpress-site/31728612?noredirect=1#comment51393417_31728612)), I removed a sidebar from a single page on my wordpress site: mrmodernmillennial.com/dividend-dashboard.

In the process, I created another issue I would like to solve. The main content of the page is still limited to the main content div, but I would like the main content to be as wide as the full width of the template.

The page template is:

```
<?php $mh_magazine_lite_options = mh_magazine_lite_theme_options(); ?> <?php get_header(); ?> <div class="mh-wrapper clearfix">

    <div id="main-content" class="mh-content"><?php
        if (have_posts()) :
            mh_before_page_content();
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <div class="entry clearfix">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div><?php
            endwhile;
            if (isset($mh_magazine_lite_options['comments_pages']) ? $mh_magazine_lite_options['comments_pages'] : false) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    if ( !is_page( 'dividend-dashboard') ) { 
        get_sidebar(); 
    } 
?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the .css template is:

```
html { font-size: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; } body { font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-size: 0.875rem; line-height: 1.6; background: #f7f7f7; word-wrap: break-word; } .fullbg .custom-background { -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; } .mh-container { width: 980px; margin: 20px auto; position: relative; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #a8a8a8; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #a8a8a8; box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #a8a8a8; } .mh-wrapper { padding: 20px; background: #fff; } .mh-content { width: 620px; overflow: hidden; } .mh-sidebar, .hp-sidebar { float: left; width: 300px; } .sb-right { margin-left: 20px; } .sb-left { margin-right: 20px; } .mh-right-sb #main-content { float: left; margin-right: 20px; } .mh-left-sb #main-content { float: right; margin-left: 20px; } .left { float: left; } .right { float: right; } .myclasswider { width:980px; overflow: hidden; background: #fff; float:left;  } .mycontent { width:980px; overflow: hidden; }
/***** Columns *****/

.row [class*='col-']:first-child { margin: 0; } [class*='col-'] { float: left; margin-left: 2.04%; overflow: hidden; }
.col-1-1 { width: 100%; }
.col-1-2 { width: 48.98%; }
.col-1-3 { width: 31.973%; }
.col-2-3 { width: 65.986%; }
.col-1-4 { width: 23.47%; }
.col-3-4 { width: 74.49%; }
.col-1-5 { width: 18.368%; }
.col-1-6 { width: 14.966%; }
.col-1-7 { width: 12.537%; }
.col-1-8 { width: 10.715%; }
.clear { clear: both; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/***** Typography *****/

h1 { font-size: 32px; font-size: 2rem; }
h2 { font-size: 24px; font-size: 1.5rem; }
h3 { font-size: 20px; font-size: 1.25rem; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; font-size: 1.125rem; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1rem; }
h6 { font-size: 14px; font-size: 0.875rem; } h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #000; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: 700; } b, strong { font-weight: bold; } i, em { font-style: italic; } small { font-size: 6px; font-size: 0.375rem; } big { font-size: 20px; font-size: 1.25rem; } pre, code { font-family: "Consolas", Courier New, Courier, monospace; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; background: #f7f7f7; border: 1px solid #ebebeb; } pre { padding: 20px; padding: 1.25rem; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -o-pre-wrap; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; } kbd { padding: 0px 6px; padding: 0rem 0.375rem; background-color: #f7f7f7; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 0.1875em; -moz-border-radius: 0.1875em; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 0.125em white inset; -webkit-border-radius: 0.1875em; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 0.125em white inset; box-shadow: 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 0.125em white inset; text-shadow: 0 0.0625em 0 #fff; } blockquote { font-size: 15px; font-size: 0.9375rem; line-height: 1.6; font-style: italic; color: #666; padding: 15px; padding: 0.9375rem; border-left: 5px solid #e64946; border-right: 2px solid #e64946; display: inline-block; box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #ccc; } sup { vertical-align: super; font-size: 10px; font-size: 0.625rem; } sub { vertical-align: sub; font-size: 10px; font-size: 0.625rem; } abbr, acronym { border-bottom: 1px dashed; cursor: help; } cite { color: #9a9b97; } q { font-style: italic; } address { font-family: "Courier new"; line-height: 1.5; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; } a:hover { color: #e64946; text-decoration: underline; } .mh-excerpt a, .widget-title a { text-decoration: none; }

/***** Lists *****/

.entry ul, .commentlist ul { list-style: square; } .entry ol, .commentlist ol { list-style: decimal; } .entry ul, .commentlist ul, .entry ol, .commentlist ol { margin: 0 0 20px 40px; margin: 0 0 1.25rem 2.5rem; } .entry ul ul, .commentlist ul ul, .entry ol ol, .commentlist ol ol { margin: 0 0 0 40px; margin: 0 0 0 2.5rem; } dl { margin: 0 0 10px 20px; margin: 0 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; } dt, dd { display: list-item; } dt { list-style-type: square; font-weight: bold; } dd { list-style-type: circle; margin-left: 20px; margin-left: 1.25rem; } select { max-width: 100%; }

/***** Header *****/

.header-wrap { background: #fff; }
.logo-wrap { padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; overflow: hidden; } .logo { display: inline-block; margin: 20px 15px; } .logo a { text-decoration: none; } .logo-name { text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #969696; border-bottom: 3px solid #000; display: inline-block; } .logo-desc { font-size: 14px; font-size: 0.875rem; color: #979797; margin-top: 5px; text-align: center; }

/***** Navigation *****/

.main-nav { background: #2a2a2a; text-transform: uppercase; border-bottom: 5px solid #e64946; } .main-nav li { float: left; position: relative; border-left: 1px solid #000; -webkit-transition: background 0.6s ease-out; -moz-transition: background 0.6s ease-out; transition: background 0.6s ease-out; } .main-nav li:first-child { border: none; } .main-nav li:hover { background: #e64946; } .main-nav li a { display: block; color: #fff; padding: 0.416em 1em; text-decoration: none; } .main-nav ul li:hover > ul { display: block; background: #2a2a2a; z-index: 9999; } .main-nav ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; } .main-nav ul ul li { width: 13em; border: none; } .main-nav ul ul ul { left: 100%; top: 0; } .main-nav .current-menu-item { background: #e64946; } .slicknav_menu { display: none; }

/***** SlickNav Mobile Menu Core Style *****/

.slicknav_btn { position: relative; display: block; vertical-align: middle; float: right; padding: 0.438rem 0.625rem; line-height: 1.125rem; cursor: pointer; } .slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt { display: block; line-height: 1.125rem; float: left; } .slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon { float: left; margin: 0.188rem 0 0 0.438rem; } .slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text { margin: 0; } .slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { display: block; width: 1.125rem; height: 0.125rem; -webkit-border-radius: 1px; -moz-border-radius: 1px; border-radius: 1px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); } .slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar + .slicknav_icon-bar { margin-top: 0.188rem } .slicknav_nav { clear: both; } .slicknav_nav ul, .slicknav_nav li { display: block; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow { font-size: 0.8rem; margin: 0 0 0 0.4rem; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { display: block; cursor: pointer; } .slicknav_nav a { display: block; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a { display: inline; } .slicknav_menu:before, .slicknav_menu:after { content: " "; display: table; } .slicknav_menu:after { clear: both; } .slicknav_menu { *zoom: 1; }

/***** SlickNav User Default Style *****/

.slicknav_menu { font-size: 13px; font-size: 0.8125rem; } .slicknav_btn { margin: 0 5px; text-decoration: none; background: #e64946; } .slicknav_menu .slicknav_menutxt { color: #fff; font-weight: bold; } .slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { background: #f5f5f5; } .slicknav_menu { background: #e64946; border-bottom: 2px solid #2a2a2a; } .slicknav_nav { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 600; color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; } .slicknav_nav, .slicknav_nav ul { list-style: none; overflow: hidden; } .slicknav_nav ul { padding: 20px 0 0 15px; border-top: 2px solid #2a2a2a; } .slicknav_nav ul ul { border: 0; padding: 0 0 0 15px; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { padding: 5px 10px; margin: 2px 5px; } .slicknav_nav a { padding: 5px 10px; margin: 2px 5px; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a { padding: 0; margin: 0; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_item:hover { background: #e64946; color: #fff; } .slicknav_nav a:hover { background: #e64946; color: #fff; } .slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode { margin-left: 15px; }

/***** FlexSlider Browser Resets *****/

.flex-container a:active, .flexslider a:active, .flex-container a:focus, .flexslider a:focus { outline: none; } .slides, .flex-control-nav, .flex-direction-nav { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }

/***** FlexSlider Default Styles *****/

.flexslider { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.flexslider .slides > li { display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; } .flexslider .slides img { display: block; } .flex-pauseplay span { text-transform: capitalize; } .slides:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; } html[xmlns] .slides { display: block; }
* html .slides { height: 1%; }
.flex-direction-nav { *height: 0; }
.flex-direction-nav a { width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -12px 0 0; display: block; background: url(images/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; } .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; display: none; } .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: -36px; display: none; } .flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled { opacity: 0.3 !important; filter: alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default; } .flexslider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 0.8; right: 5px; display: block; } .flexslider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 0.8; left: 5px; display: block; } .flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover { opacity: 1; } .flex-control-nav { width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 6px; text-align: center; } .flex-control-nav li { margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline; } .flex-control-paging li a { width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); } .flex-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); } .flex-control-paging li a.flex-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); cursor: default; }

/***** FlexSlider Custom Styles *****/

.flexslider { position: relative; zoom: 1; } .flex-viewport { max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease; } .loading .flex-viewport { max-height: 300px; } .flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; } .no-js .slides > li:first-child { display: block; } .slider-normal { width: 620px; max-width: 100%; } .slide-caption { width: 25em; max-width: 100%; position: absolute; background: #2a2a2a; color: #fff; top: 0; right: 0; border-bottom: 3px solid #e64946; opacity: 0.6; filter: alpha(opacity=60); } .slide-wrap:hover .slide-caption { opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); } .slide-title { color: #fff; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 0.625rem; } .slide-title:hover { color: #e64946; } .slide-data { padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; }

/***** Posts/Pages *****/

.post-header { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .entry-title { padding-bottom: 3px; padding-bottom: 0.1875rem; } .page-title-top, .subheading-top { border-bottom: 3px solid #2a2a2a; } .page-title { font-size: 24px; font-size: 1.5rem; color: #fff; padding: 0px 10px 3px; padding: 0rem 0.625rem 0.1875rem; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; background: #e64946; display: inline-block; } .subheading { font-size: 15px; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #fff; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: 400; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 0.625rem; padding: 2px 7px 3px; padding: 0.125rem 0.4375rem 0.1875rem; background: #e64946; display: inline-block; } .meta, .meta a { font-size: 13px; font-size: 0.8125rem; color: #979797; } .post-meta { margin-top: 10px; margin-top: 0.625rem; padding: 5px; padding: 0.3125rem; border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; } .post-meta a { color: #979797; font-weight: 600; } .post-meta a:hover { color: #e64946; } .post-thumbnail { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .post-thumbnail img { width: 100%; } .entry h1, .entry h2, .entry h3, .entry h4, .entry h5, .entry h6, .entry p, .entry blockquote, .entry .flex-vid, .entry row, .entry .mh-video-container { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .entry blockquote p:last-child { margin: 0; } .entry a { color: #e64946; } .post-tags { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .post-tags li { float: left; margin: 0px 6px 6px 0px; margin: 0rem 0.375rem 0.375rem 0rem; background: #555555; } .post-tags li:hover { background: #e64946; } .post-tags a, .post-tags a:hover { color: #fff; padding: 2px 10px; padding: 0.125rem 0.625rem; display: block; text-decoration: none; } .section-title { padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; background: #f6f6f6; border: 1px solid #d7d8d8; } .sticky { }

/***** Authorbox *****/

.author-box { line-height: 1.5; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; background: #f7f7f7; border-top: 3px solid #e64946; border-bottom: 3px solid #e64946; } .author-box-wrap { padding: 10px; } .author-box-avatar { float: left; margin-right: 10px; } .author-box-name { margin-bottom: 10px; }

/***** Loop / Archives / Search Results *****/

.loop-wrap { padding-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 1.25rem; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; } .loop-data { margin-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 0.625rem; } .loop-thumb { float: left; margin-right: 20px; } .cat-desc { margin-bottom: 30px; margin-bottom: 1.875rem; padding: 20px; padding: 1.25rem; background: #f7f7f7; border-top: 3px solid #e64946; border-bottom: 3px solid #e64946; }

/***** Pagination *****/

.post .pagination { padding-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 1.25rem; } .page-numbers { padding: 5px 10px; padding: 0.3125rem 0.625rem; background: #eee; display: inline-block; } .page-numbers:hover, .current, a:hover .pagelink { background: #e64946; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; } .page-numbers a { display: block; } .pagelink { padding: 5px 10px; padding: 0.3125rem 0.625rem; background: #e64946; color: #fff; } a .pagelink { background: #eee; color: #444; } .post-nav a { font-size: 15px; font-size: 0.9375rem; }

/***** Footer *****/

footer { font-size: 13px; font-size: 0.8125rem; color: #fff; padding: 20px; padding: 1.25rem; background: #2a2a2a; } footer a { color: #f7f7f7; } .copyright-wrap { background: #2a2a2a; border-top: 3px solid #999; } .copyright { font-size: 11px; font-size: 0.6875rem; padding: 2px 10px; padding: 0.125rem 0.625rem; color: #999; } .copyright a { color: #999; }

/***** Images / Video *****/

img { max-width: 100%; width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ height: auto; vertical-align: bottom; } iframe, embed, object, video { max-width: 100%; } .mh-video-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden; } .mh-video-container iframe, .mh-video-container object, .mh-video-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; } .alignnone { display: block; margin: 20px 0; margin: 1.25rem 0; } .aligncenter { display: block; margin: 20px auto; margin: 1.25rem auto; } .alignleft { display: inline; float: left; margin: 5px 20px 20px 0; margin: 0.3125rem 1.25rem 1.25rem 0; } .alignright { display: inline; float: right; margin: 5px 0 20px 20px; margin: 0.3125rem 0 1.25rem 1.25rem; } } .wp-caption { max-width: 100%; } .wp-caption-text { font-size: 12px; font-size: 0.75rem; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1.4; color: #000; margin-top: 5px; margin-top: 0.3125rem; display: block; } .alignnone .wp-caption-text, .aligncenter .wp-caption-text, .alignleft .wp-caption-text, .alignright .wp-caption-text { margin-bottom: 0; } .gallery dl { margin: 0; } .gallery dt { list-style: none; } .gallery-caption { position: relative; display: none; }

/***** Tables *****/

table { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb; border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb; } td, th { padding: 5px 10px; padding: 0.3125rem 0.625rem; border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; } th { background-color: #f9f9f9; font-weight: 600; color: #000; }

/***** Widgets *****/

.widget-title, .footer-widget-title { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .footer-widget-title { color: #fff; } .widget-title, .footer-widget-title { border-bottom: 3px solid #e64946; padding-bottom: 3px; } .sb-widget, .footer-widget { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; overflow: hidden; }

/***** MH Custom Posts Widget *****/

.sb-widget .cp-wrap { padding: 15px 0px; padding: 0.9375rem 0rem; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; } .footer-widget .cp-wrap { padding: 5px 0px; padding: 0.3125rem 0rem; border-bottom: 1px solid #454545; } .cp-widget li:first-child { padding-top: 0; } .cp-thumb { float: left; margin-right: 10px; margin-right: 0.625rem; } .cp-widget-title { font-weight: 700; line-height: 1.3; } .cp-small .meta { font-size: 11px; font-size: 0.6875rem; } .home-wide .cp-small { float: left; width: 50%; min-height: 55px; } .home-wide .cp-small .cp-data { margin-right: 10px; } .home-wide .cp-widget .cp-small:first-child { padding-top: 15px; padding-top: 0.9375rem; }

/***** Default WordPress Widgets *****/

.sb-widget .menu > .menu-item, .sb-widget .cat-item { padding: 5px 0px; padding: 0.375rem 0rem; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; } .footer-widget .menu > .menu-item, .footer-widget .cat-item { padding: 5px 0px; padding: 0.3125rem 0rem; border-bottom: 1px solid #454545; } .sb-widget .menu-item:first-child, .sb-widget .cat-item:first-child, .footer-widget .menu-item:first-child, .footer-widget .cat-item:first-child { padding-top: 0; } .sb-widget .menu-item, .sb-widget .cat-item, .footer-widget .menu-item, .footer-widget .cat-item { line-height: 1.3; } #wp-calendar caption { text-align: left; padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; background: #f7f7f7; } #wp-calendar th, #wp-calendar td { padding: 5px 10px; padding: 0.3125rem 0.625rem; text-align: center; } #wp-calendar th { font-weight: 300; } #wp-calendar #prev { text-align: left; } .tagcloud a { margin: 2px; margin: 0.125rem; padding: 2px 10px; padding: 0.125rem 0.625rem; color: #666; white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; } .sb-widget .tagcloud a { background: #f6f6f6; } .footer-widget .tagcloud a { background: #000; } .tagcloud a:hover, .sb-widget .tagcloud a:hover, .footer-widget .tagcloud a:hover { color: #fff; background: #e64946; text-decoration: none; }

/***** Comments *****/

.no-comments { padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; margin-top: 20px; margin-top: 1.25rem; background: #f6f6f6; border: 1px solid #d7d8d8; } .commentlist { margin-bottom: 40px; margin-bottom: 2.5rem; list-style: none; } .commentlist .comment .vcard { line-height: 2.5; padding: 10px 0px; padding: 0.625rem 0rem; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; } .commentlist .comment .avatar { width: 2.5em; height: 2.5em; padding: 2px; padding: 0.125rem; margin-right: 6px; margin-right: 0.375rem; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #f7f7f7; vertical-align: middle; } .commentlist .bypostauthor .vcard { border-left: 3px solid #e64946; } .commentlist .bypostauthor .avatar { margin-left: 6px; margin-left: 0.375rem; } .commentlist .children { list-style: none; } .commentlist h1, .commentlist h2, .commentlist h3, .commentlist h4, .commentlist h5, .commentlist h6 { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .comment-text p, .comment-text blockquote { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .comment-text blockquote p:last-child { margin: 0; } .comment-info { color: #e64946; margin: 20px 0px; margin: 1.25rem 0rem; } .comments-pagination { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .pinglist { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } .pinglist .pings:first-child { border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb; } .pinglist .pings { line-height: 2.5; padding: 10px 0px; padding: 0.625rem 0rem; border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb; }

/***** Forms *****/

input { font-size: 12px; font-size: 0.75rem; padding: 5px; padding: 0.3125rem; border: 1px solid #d7d8d8; -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; } input[type=text] { width: 60%; } input[type=text]:hover, textarea:hover { border: 1px solid #e64946; } input[type=submit] { min-width: 75px; color: #fff; padding: 5px 10px; padding: 0.3125rem 0.625rem; background: #e64946; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear; transition: all 0.1s linear; border: 0; -webkit-appearance: none; } input[type=submit]:hover { background: #2a2a2a; } textarea { width: 96%; line-height: 1.5; padding: 5px; padding: 0.3125rem; border: 1px solid #d7d8d8; }

/***** Comment Form *****/

#respond { padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; background: #f6f6f6; border: 1px solid #d7d8d8; } #respond h3 { margin-bottom: 20px; margin-bottom: 1.25rem; } #commentform p { margin-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 0.625rem; } #cancel-comment-reply-link { font-size: 12px; font-size: 0.75rem; background: #e64946; padding: 5px; padding: 0.3125rem; color: #fff; } #cancel-comment-reply-link:hover { background: #2a2a2a; text-decoration: none; } .required { color: #e64946; }

/***** Contact Form 7 *****/

.wpcf7-form { font-size: 12px; font-size: 0.75rem; padding: 10px; padding: 0.625rem; border: 1px solid #d7d8d8; background: #f7f7f7; } .wpcf7-form input[type=email] { width: 60%; } .wpcf7-form input[type=email]:hover { border: 1px solid #e64946; } .wpcf7-form p { margin-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 0.625rem; } .wpcf7-response-output { background: #fff; }

/***** Searchform *****/

#searchform { padding: 5px; padding: 0.3125rem; background: #f6f6f6; border: 1px solid #ebebeb; overflow: hidden; } #searchform #s { width: 100%; font-size: 12px; font-size: 0.75rem; color: #444; background: none; border: none; } #searchform #s:focus { outline: none; } #searchsubmit { display: none; }

/***** Shortcodes *****/

.ad-label { font-size: 10px; font-size: 0.625rem; }

/***** Media Queries *****/

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .mh-container { width: 768px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .mh-content { width: 488px; }
    .mh-sidebar, .hp-sidebar { width: 220px; }
    .hp-sidebar-left, .hp-sidebar-right { width: 234px; } } @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .mh-container { width: 90%; min-width: 300px; }
    [class*='col-'], .mh-content, .mh-right-sb #main-content, .mh-left-sb #main-content, .mh-sidebar, .hp-sidebar { width: 100%; margin: 0; }
    .mh-sidebar { margin-top: 20px; }
    .logo-wrap { border-bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb; }
    .home-wide .cp-small { float: none; width: 100%; min-height: 0; }
    .home-wide .cp-small .cp-data { margin-right: 0; }
    .home-wide .cp-widget .cp-small:first-child { padding-top: 0; }
    .slide-wrap img { width: 100%; }
    .js .slicknav_menu { display: block; }
    .js .main-nav { display: none; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    .logo-wrap { text-align: center; }
    .logo-name { font-size: 24px; font-size: 1.5rem; }
    .logo-desc { font-size: 14px; font-size: 0.875rem; }
    .loop-thumb { float: none; margin: 0 0 20px; }
    .slide-caption { position: relative; width: 100%; bottom: 0; top: auto; border-top: 3px solid #e64946; border-bottom: none; opacity: 1; }
    .flex-control-nav { display: none; }
    .commentlist ul, .commentlist ol, .commentlist ul ul, .commentlist ol ol { margin: 0 0 20px 0; margin: 0 0 1.25rem 0; } }
```

Ultimately, I would like to extend the main content to a width of 980 px when is_page(dividend-dashboard).

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot.

PHP:

```
<?php $mh_magazine_lite_options = mh_magazine_lite_theme_options(); ?> <?php get_header(); ?> <div class="mh-wrapper clearfix">

    <div id="main-content" class="mh-content <?php if ( is_page('dividend-dashboard') ) {echo " wide";} ?>"><?php
        if (have_posts()) :
            mh_before_page_content();
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <div class="entry clearfix">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div><?php
            endwhile;
            if (isset($mh_magazine_lite_options['comments_pages']) ? $mh_magazine_lite_options['comments_pages'] : false) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    if ( !is_page( 'dividend-dashboard') ) { 
        get_sidebar(); 
    } 
?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Add to CSS:

```
.mh-content.wide {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hey @hopkins-matt, thanks for the help. I updated the page.php and .css. It's so close! It looks like there is another piece to the puzzle, because it doesn't extend to 100%. I am thinking there is another piece of .css that specifies some right-padding or something?

Comment: The above code extends the content area to 100% width. The issue is that the content you've added is setting an inline width of 804px. You'll need to take a look at the content you're adding to see where you can modify this inline width. Otherwise, it could be modified with javascript, but that is not ideal.

Comment: you were absolutely correct. I changed the embed for the object to a larger px and it worked. Thanks so much.